# Perl: How to pass information to a function in module?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Completely new to Perl here. Anyway, I was given a certain task and I found a perl module online that does *exactly* what I want.

[Matrix](http://jaspar.genereg.net/html/DOWNLOAD/jaspar_CORE/non_redundant/by_tax_group/vertebrates/matrix_only/matrix_only.txt)

[Documentation](http://tfbs.genereg.net/DOC/)

This is the documentation for the perl module -- under Ext there is one called pwmsearch, which does exactly what I need.

So I tried to write a script that starts out something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict; 
use TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch; #this was how the documentation said in synopsis part for pwmsearch so I figured this was how to do it
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how I am supposed to pass objects to pwmsearch. The source code of pwmsearch as shown in the documentation above says it takes in $matrixobj and $seqobj, which I have stored as files matrix and sequence.

So after googling around on what I could try, I tried doing things like:

```
pwmsearch('matrix','sequence');
```

or

```
open FILE, 'matrix.txt' or die "Couldn't open file";
$matrix.=<FILE>
close FILE;

open FILE, 'sequence' or die "Couldn't open file";
$seq.=<FILE>
close FILE;
pwmsearch($matrix,$seq)
```

But all of them makes perl bark at me with various errors. What am I doing wrong and what could I do to fix them?

Comment: `$matrixobj` has to be some kind of object (since I see a method called on it), as the name implies. It probably has to be an object of one of the TFBS::Matrix::* classes.

Comment: `$seqobj` also has to be an object of some kind (since I see a method called on it), though I see no class with "Sequence" in the name.

Comment: Probably a [Bio::Seq](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/Seq.pm) object - see http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/SeqIO.pm.

Comment: I have confirmed that it should be a Bio::Seq object.

Comment: @MvanGeest I already looked at that, but being new with perl it wasn't very helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: I see that $seqobj should be a Bio::Seq object -- but pwmsearch does that for me. So again, back to my original question -- what is the best way to pass these files to pwmsearch? Nothing I can find seems to work.

Comment: No, `pwmsearch` does not do that fort you. It's an input to `pwmsearch`. `pwmsearch` does not take files.

Comment: @ikegami from what little I know about perl it seemed like looking at pwmsearch the block of code starting with my $seqfile seemed to do that. So what would be the best way to pass these files to pwmsearch? I can't seem to be able to find the way online.

Comment: The first line is `my ($matrixobj, $seqobj, $threshold, $start, $end) = @_;`. As you can see, `$seqobj` is an input. Again, `pwmsearch` doesn't take files. The code you mentioned gets a file name from the Bio::Seq object.

Comment: @ikegami Ok... so in other words, I should turn the files into Bio::Seq objects somehow, and then call pwmsearch($matrixobj, $seqobj,...)?

Comment: Yup. That's as far as I got (and as far as I'll go).

Comment: @ikegami Ok. So I just did that, and when I call pwmsearch($matrixobj, $seqobj,...) (yes I turned them into bio::seq objects) perl complains that I called a undefined subroutine &main::pwmsearch ... I don't understand. I called use TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch, so shouldn't that be enough for me to use pwmsearch?

Comment: If it doesn't export the method, you have to refer to it by full name, i.e. `TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch($matrixobj, $seqobj)`

Comment: @tripleee No I tried that too, and that gave me the same error except it said undefined subroutine &TFBS::EXT::...

Comment: The sub is in package `TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch`, not `TFBS::Ext`. The following should work: `use TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch; TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch::pwmsearch(...)`. I can't tell for sure without seeing the source, but I think `use TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch qw( pwmsearch ); pwmsearch(...)` will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is documentation how to generate pwm matrix object: http://tfbs.genereg.net/DOC/TFBS/Matrix/PWM.html

```
use TFBS::Matrix::PWM;
my $matrixstring = <<ENDMATRIX
 0.61 -3.16  1.83 -3.16  1.21 -0.06
-0.15 -2.57 -3.16 -3.16 -2.57 -1.83
-1.57  1.85 -2.57 -1.34 -1.57  1.14
 0.31 -3.16 -2.57  1.76  0.24 -0.83
ENDMATRIX;
my $pwm_matrix_in = TFBS::Matrix::PWM->new(-matrixstring => $matrixstring,
                 -name         => "MyProfile",
                 -ID           => "M0001"
                );
```

PWMSearch docs: http://tfbs.genereg.net/DOC/Ext/pwmsearch.html

It needs five input variables: $matrixobj, $seqobj, $threshold, $start, $end, the last 3 is optional if I see correctly.

The seqobj is most probably a Bio::Seq compatible object. Create a new object from a file:
Docs: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::SeqIO](http://metacpan.org/pod/Bio%3a%3aSeqIO)

```
use Bio::SeqIO;
my $seqobj_in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "inputfilename" ,
                           -format => 'Fasta');


use strict; 
use TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch;
TFBS::Ext::pwmsearch::pwmsearch($pwm_matrix_in,$seqobj_in);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Ah, I had already figured it out -- thanks for the help though!